# Uninstalling Go (golang)

Tags: uninstall

I'm trying to install [drive](https://github.com/odeke-em/drive), which requires [Go](https://golang.org/).

I did:

```
sudo apt-get install golang git mercurial
```

which successfully installed version 1.2.1. Unfortunately, when I tried to install drive with:

```
go get -u github.com/odeke-em/drive/cmd/drive
```

I encountered [this error](https://github.com/odeke-em/drive/issues/223), and now I see I need at least version 1.4 of Go to make things work. The golang doc says you must first remove the existing version.

So I came across [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/720260/updating-golang-on-ubuntu) that says to simply use:

```
sudo apt-get purge golang
```

which gave me this output:

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:
golang*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 16 not upgraded.
After this operation, 92.2 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 263287 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing golang (2:1.2.1-2ubuntu1) ...
```

(no more output after the three dots—just back to the prompt).

But I still see the `go` directory in `/usr/lib/`, and there's also still a `gopath` directory in my home directory.

which I think was created when I did:

```
$ cat << ! >> ~/.bashrc
> export GOPATH=\$HOME/gopath
> export PATH=\$GOPATH:\$GOPATH/bin:\$PATH
> !
$ source ~/.bashrc # To reload the settings and get the newly set ones # Or open a fresh terminal
```

during the installation (to create the GOPATH).

So I'm not sure if the uninstall was successful and if it's safe to install a newer version of Go.

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: To downvoter: Are you kidding me?

Comment: You get my upvote for the downvoter.  Stop that drive-by downvote crap.  This is a seriously annoying problem, I was glad to find the question, thanks.

Answer (score 39):

I spent a whole morning fixing this, tried all different solutions, when I type `go version`, it's still there, really annoying...

This worked for me.

```
sudo apt-get remove golang-go
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove golang-go
```

[Check this original post :D](https://www.howtoinstall.co/en/ubuntu/trusty/golang-go?action=remove)

Comment: `--auto-remove` force it to remove all from linux-images which consumed around 10 minutes. @loukaswho

Answer (score 14):

I realize that this is a little old, but the answers at https://golang.org/doc/manage-install#uninstalling may help you.

Essentially just removing the directories `/usr/local/go` or `/usr/lib/go` and modifying your path at `/etc/profile` or `$HOME/.profile` should be enough.

Answer (score 3):

best way to uninstall is to open terminal and type

```
sudo apt-get uninstall purge golang*
```

this removes every package associated with go.
Then you can run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

But if you did that and nothing worked, you can do this

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/go
```

then try running the purge again.
But You should update to Go 1.8, which sets the GOPATH for you.
But hey! before updating first remove existing golang.

Answer (score 3):

First you have to remove all the go-packages in your system by type this code from terminal

```
sudo apt-get purge golang*
```

Then follow the instructions to download and install golang

[Official golang website](https://golang.org)

Comment: Thanks,  this was the only solution that worked

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [official docs](https://go.dev/doc/manage-install)

1. Firstly, delete the go directory. Mostly it will be /usr/local/go. If you are not sure check it using `which go`. So, run `sudo rm -rf /usr/local/go`.
2. Next you need to remove the Go bin directory from your PATH environment variable. i.e. remove GOBIN, GOPATH from ~/.bashrc.