# Snapcraft - Build snap using a specific golang version

Tags: compiling, snap, golang

I have been trying to build my application via snap. However, snap uses go version `1.6` by default. I need at least `go 1.10` though. How'd I go on about that?

I couldn't find anything useful in the snapcraft documentation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installation instructions for golang 1.9 into Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/959932/installation-instructions-for-golang-1-9-into-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: Golang 1.6 is the version which comes in 16.04, which is the target for building snaps. If you want to use a different version, you'll need to change your build script to add a PPA or pull a newer version by some other means, and then use the new version to build your app.

Comment: can i change the target to 18.04?

Comment: Not before there is an Ubuntu Core 18 release, no. I don't think that's happened yet.

Comment: I might just look at how to write an own plugin, so others can benefit from it :)