# Can't Install Go

Tags: 19.04, tar, golang, xvfb

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y upgrade
wget https://dl.google.com/go/go1.12.6.linux-amd64.tar.gz
```

using this command I download Go to my device after that I try to extract the downloaded archive and install it to the desired location on the system. using below command

```
sudo tar -xvf go1.13.3.linux-amd64.tar.gz 
sudo mv go /usr/local
```

but I got error

```
sudo tar -xvf go1.12.6.linux-amd64.tar.gz
tar: go1.12.6.linux-amd64.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

what should I do?

Comment: Your extraction line is wrong.  It should be `tar zxvf go1.12.6.linux-amd64.tar.gz`.  Also, why do you have a line about 13.3, when your question is about 12.6?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Updating golang on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/720260/updating-golang-on-ubuntu) go programming language is an [Ubuntu package](https://askubuntu.com/a/1091681). To install it search for "golang" in the Ubuntu Software app.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer to your question

Download the tarball for `go`

```
wget https://dl.google.com/go/go1.12.6.linux-amd64.tar.gz
```

Extract the tarball

```
tar -xzf go1.12.6.linux-amd64.tar.gz
```

Move the Folder to `/usr/local/`

```
sudo mv go /usr/local/
```

Add `/usr/local/go/bin` to the `PATH`

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin
```

Comment: What's the point of installing third-party software from the internet when the golang package in Ubuntu Software is exactly the same version as the file from https://dl.google.com that you mentioned? Google doesn't 100% maintain their own go software for the Ubuntu platform. As a result I and people like me have to do some of it instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47420118.

Comment: First of all, let me clarify that method does NOT install third party software. The package is downloaded directly from the google server (Go was designed at Google). Also, installing go using `apt install golang` (same with Ubuntu software center) might be a bad idea because the Ubuntu repo contains an older version. Also, OP has already downloaded the tarball, so i would like to know what is the point of wasting data by downloading again?

Comment: By third party I meant not from the principal Ubuntu software sources which in this case are 1. The Ubuntu iso file which was used to install Ubuntu. 2. Ubuntu Software and the default Ubuntu repositories. By "third-party" I mean any software that comes from "somewhere else". Maybe I shouldn't use the phrase third-party anymore since it makes people think that software that is downloaded from the internet is vetted equivalently in Ubuntu to software from Ubuntu Software.

Comment: "sudo mv go /usr/local/" when I try this command, $ sudo mv go /usr/local/
mv: cannot move 'go' to '/usr/local/go': Directory not empty

Comment: I have just installed `go` using the same procedure in a virtual machine. I have recorded the process in this video https://imgur.com/a/ccjSsBV (286 KB, 38s)

Comment: Thank you dr, for your help :-)3